# How to do calculation using many-to-many relationship in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, many-to-many

I have a database having the following structure. Each book can have multiple authors, and each author can write multiple books.

```
[book:book_id, book_name, book_price]
[author: author_id, author_name]
[link:book_id, author_id]
```

{book_id's and author_id's are linked. the complete structure is shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIFNU.png}

Now each book has a price (currency). 30% of the price should be equally distributed to each author who have contributed to the book. 
**My question is how to find the total payment for each author for a particular year.**

*[I thought of a solution my self. I could do only up to step 1. If you can provide me some hints or materials where I can find how do such manipulations, it would be very helpful]*

Algorithm of my solution is:

1. So for each book_id, I need to find the number of author_id's in the middle table who has the same book_id. (could do it by query)
2. If I divide the book_price by number_of_author_in_book and multiply it with 30/100, I get the money for that book that will go to the each  author's account for that book (say payment_of_one_author_in_book)
3. For each author_id in the middle table, I look up for the corresponding book_id and add the payment_of_one_author_in_book for that author_id to a new variable (author_payment_this_year) corresponding to the author ID, if the year matches to the query year.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This example includes aliases and subqueries.

```
SELECT 
    a.author_id,
    a.author_name,
    SUM(share.auth_share) AS author_total
FROM (link l
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        b.book_id,
        ( [b.book_price] * 0.3 ) / [no_auth] AS auth_share
    FROM book b
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            l.book_id,
            COUNT(l.author_id) AS no_auth
        FROM   link l
        GROUP  BY l.book_id) AS ac
    ON b.book_id = ac.book_id) AS share
ON l.book_id = share.book_id)
INNER JOIN author a
ON l.author_id = a.author_id
GROUP BY a.author_id,a.author_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT author.AuthorId, author.Author_name, book.Book_Name, book.Book_Price, [Book_Price]/DCount("[Author_id]","[Link]","[Book_id]=" & [Book_Id]) AS Share
FROM (author INNER JOIN link AS link_1 ON author.AuthorId = link_1.Author_id) INNER JOIN book ON link_1.Book_id = book.Book_Id;
```

Basically, it is just a join of the three tables.  The only tricky bit is using DCount function to add up how many authors in Link share this book_ID